# Using Client's Non-exportable Private Key from Windows Cert Store in Mutual SSL Authentication

Tags: windows

In `SSL`, for `Client Certificate Authentication`, we have to use `Windows Certificate Store`. So client's certificate and associated private key is stored in windows store by importing PFX file containing client cert. and private key in store. While importing the pfx file we have to made `private key` as `non-exportable`.

Now how to use this key and cert for creating ssl connection.

I have gone openssl engines like `capi engine` but didn't helped a lot.

Comment: [Use SChannel?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa378819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)